# How to add hyperlink in mail using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, function, email

I have to add hyperlink into my mail function. But when there has been sent an email, I dont get the  tag, but the fully code like "click here" I just want an email without seeing the  tag in my mail. This is the code I am using:

```
function stuurMail($email, $verificationCode)
{
    $tekst = "";
    $receiver= $email;
    $topic = "Bevestiging aanmelding EenmaalAndermaal";
    $tekst .= "Bedankt voor uw aanmelding!\nOm gebruik te kunnen maken van het platform, dient u via het onderstaande link uw account te activeren!\n";
    $tekst .= "<a href=\"test_functie.php\">http://test.nl/test.php?check=$verificationCode</a>";
    $header = "From: blabla@gmail.com";
    mail($receiver, $topic, $tekst, $header);
}
```

Comment: research string concatenation

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Not sure how that could help this person. The OP does string concatenation well. What's the problem?

Comment: @PraveenKumar they escape the string - that isn't concatenation

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I still don't get it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar string concatenation as in using this: `echo $my_var. '-' .$another_var` :)

Comment: just also saw that the hyper link references a file - when that sends that should be a full url address, it won't search every single site for `foo.php`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `$name = "Two Thumbs"; echo "Hello $name!";` - This works mate! `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry I'm unsure what your point is with the last comment? :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs You don't need to concatenate two strings only using `.`. The `"` can expand variables.

Comment: @PraveenKumar true, but it's a lot cleaner and easier to read/determine vars in a string - it's just better practice :) and doesn't encourage the idea of SQL injection (obviously not too related but if they get into them using vars inside double quotes, then when they get to SQL then they'll chuck it in without thought) - also single quotes are faster, just so many more benefits to concatting :)

Comment: Agreed mate! @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the email to be a HTML email and not a plain-text one. Update your header this way:

```
$header = "From: blabla@gmail.com\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
```

Comment: Thank you, but i do now get this  [test_functie.php]http://test.nl/verificatie.php?check=3FLY2UpY

Comment: Woah... Sorry??

Comment: The link has not been clickable

Comment: @Emre Try changing it to: `$tekst .= "<a href=\"http://test.nl/test.php?check=$verificationCode\">http://test.nl/test.php?check=$verificationCode</a>";`

Comment: Or do this as single quotes are faster: `$tekst .= '<a href="http://test.nl/test.php?check=' . $verificationCode . '">http://test.nl/test.php?check=' . $verificationCode . '</a>';` this can be done for all of your code, remember code such as `"\r\n"` etc is always in need of double quotes, otherwise it wont work..

Comment: @Emre Oh did you see what exactly is being sent to the email client? Sorry was out for lunch.